# IIS URL Rewrite behaves differently for HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

I've been trying to use the URL Rewrite module to create a rule that looks for any set of two or more forward-slashes in the URL (past the first set) that will redirect the browser to a URL with all sets of multiple forward slashes replaced with just one.  Example:

http://myhost.com/abc//def//ghi//jkl//iisstart.png

should redirect to

http://myhost.com/abc/def/ghi/jkl/iisstart.png﻿

I already understand that IIS sees these two URLs as functionally equivalent, but for this public-facing site we want to avoid any chance that crawlers will index URLs with the multiple forward slashes; hence the redirection.  So here's the rule I put together:

```
<rule name="Redirect URLs with Multiple Forward Slashes" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="{URL}" appendQueryString="true" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="//" />
   </conditions>
</rule>
```

I tested this on my local box, and it produced the expected outcome (the redirection).  I copied it into a web.config on a development server and tried it out, but it didn't work.  I even took the path of making sure the URL Rewrite installation matched the version on the development server (it's 2.0, and upgrading would be a pain in our large production server farm so I'd like to avoid that).  After that, I took into account that our development server, by design, only serves up HTTPS, while I'd been testing in HTTP on my local box.  When I enabled HTTPS on my local box, the rewrite rule didn't work with an HTTPS URL but worked fine with an HTTP URL pointing to the same resource.

All the URL Rewrite documentation I've looked at makes reference to HTTP, and there are no references to HTTPS.  What am I doing wrong here?

For the record - my local box is running Windows 10, and has IIS version 10.  The dev server is running Server 2012, and has IIS version 7.5.

Comment: I've tested your rule with HTTPS. And it's working fine. Maybe another rule above is changing behaviour. Can you please put this rule at the top of your rules in web.config?

Comment: I find this approach useful to troubleshoot issues with rewrite rules https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules